# Navigate on another website using Javascript (Fill out a searchField and click search)

Tags: javascript

It is just that, I have a button that opens the website, but I can't figure out how to fill that field on that website and search for the String that I'm providing. 
 I really don't know where to look for this.

Right now, I open the website with :`window.open(url);` but that's it.

Using console, I can fill the txtInput using this `$('#txtBuscar').val('geo');`

Then click the button with this: `$('#btnBuscar').click();`

But I don't know how to do this from my function...
Any ideas on what to use?

Website is https://www.mercadopublico.cl/Home

Comment: they have API  server?

Comment: They don't, that's why I'm trying to figure out how to do it. I'm not quite sure if it's possible. I'm kinda new to Javascript

Comment: you cant do it , you need to use python or php i belive there is a module on pyton that will allow you to do it , but you cant do it with pure js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this without getting a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) error.

Unless the site you are accessing allows it, you cannot access the code.

See [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work/10636765?s=35|54.6015#10636765) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that. Because when you use `window.open(url);` the browser opens a new window with url, but you script will be running in the previous window.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the new site open up in an iframe on your page and then navigate the dom with your pages javaScript.